# Primefaces autoComplete change separator

Tags: primefaces, autocomplete

I am using primefaces autoComplete in my JSF page. The separator which it uses is comma. I am splitting the data to convert data of autoComplete to Array. Now issue is that my dataitems in autoComplete contains ", ". When I use Split in my data item, then it splits my data to. For example:

[mydataitem1, mydataitem 2, mydataitem, 3 ,.....]
Now Array becomes

mydataitem1
mydataitem 2
mydataitem
3
...

```
<p:autoComplete id="someId" multiple="true" value="${someBean.SomeValue}"
    completeMethod="${someBean.completeMethod}" var="value"
    itemLabel="value" itemValue="#{title}" forceSelection="true">
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText  value="#{title}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{someBean.action}" process="@form" /> 
</p:autoComplete>
```

Is there any attribute of autoComplete where I can change the comma to some other character?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but where is autocomplete using comma as separator?

Comment: Thnks @JaqenH'ghar for your reply. I modified my question. Now it contains the primefaces autoComplete which on action function sends value in a comma seperated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you'll have to bind into a List when using `multiple="true"`. If you just use Strings you can just bind to a `List<String>`, if you use a complex object you'll have to use `List<MyObject>` and add a converter.

Note: if you print out the list in the log, it will still write

```
[mydataitem1, mydataitem 2, mydataitem 3,.....]
```

but that's just the toString()-method that delimits with comma.

Also, you have errors in `itemLabel` and `itemValue`, and should just always use `#{}` instead of `${}`.

And I think `process="@form"` can be a bit dangerous, as if you have other input components in the form that fails validation/conversion the listener will not be called. I'd just remove it (default is process="@this").

Comment: I have removed the process="@form" and also without any .toString() still the value is wit comma seperated. Following is the code


`public void action(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){`
`Object  object = ((UIOutput) event.getSource()).getValue();`
`String  myVal = "";`
`myVal = ((UIOutput) event.getSource()).getValue().toString();`
`}`

Comment: The value is available in someBean.SomeValue when the listener is called. And if someValue is a List<String> you have it all there, no need to look in the event (as I understand it)

Comment: Ok it works fine now. I understand. Thanks a lot @Jaqen